# Edit an XML with PHP. Only first time works, why?

Tags: php, xml

So my problem is that when I'm editing an XML file (below) with some PHP lines, everything works the first time, and then it deletes false lines and creates the new ones in the wrong places.

Here the PHP script for deleting the rows:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

// The file
$filePath = '/....../test/test.xml';

// Grab file into an array, by lines
$fileArr = file($filePath);

// Remove desired line
unset($fileArr[7]); // $fileArr[15] == line #16
unset($fileArr[16]); // idem
unset($fileArr[25]); // idem

//Put back with PHP5
file_put_contents($filePath, implode('', $fileArr ));

session_destroy(); 
?>
```

Here the PHP script to write new rows

```
<?php
session_start(); 

// The file
$filePath = '/....../test/test.xml';

// Grab file into an array, by lines
$fileArr = file($filePath);

//Change
$etichettaasse = "\t\t\t\t<string>\t14 gen</string>\n\r";
$medianord =  "\t\t\t\t<number>\t280\t</number>\n\r";
$mediasud =  "\t\t\t\t<number>\t280\t</number>\n\r";

// Replace line
$fileArr[11] = $etichettaasse;
$fileArr[19] = $medianord;
$fileArr[27] = $mediasud;

// Implode and save
file_put_contents($filePath, implode('', $fileArr ));

session_destroy(); 
?>
```

Here the **original** XML:

```
<chart>
<axis_category color='ffffff' skip='0' size='12' alpha='80' />
<axis_value color='ffffff' skip='10' size='12' show_min='false' min="80" max="130"  />
<chart_border top_thickness='1' bottom_thickness='1' left_thickness='1' right_thickness='1' />              
<chart_data>
    <row>
        <null/>
            <string>    3 dic</string>
            <string>    10 dic</string>
            <string>    17 dic</string>
            <string>    24 dic</string>
            <string>    31 dic</string>

    </row>
    <row>
        <string>Media Nord</string>
            <number>    102.72  </number>
            <number>    101.60  </number>
            <number>    101.85  </number>
            <number>    101.84  </number>
            <number>    101.84  </number>

    </row>
    <row>
        <string>Media Sud</string>
            <number>    102.28  </number>
            <number>    101.24  </number>
            <number>    101.70  </number>
            <number>    101.88  </number>
            <number>    101.88  </number>

    </row>
</chart_data>
</chart>
```

After the first round of PHP script, it is updated as requested:

```
<chart>
<axis_category color='ffffff' skip='0' size='12' alpha='80' />
<axis_value color='ffffff' skip='10' size='12' show_min='false' min="80" max="130"  />
<chart_border top_thickness='1' bottom_thickness='1' left_thickness='1' right_thickness='1' />              
<chart_data>
    <row>
        <null/>
            <string>    10 dic</string>
            <string>    17 dic</string>
            <string>    24 dic</string>
            <string>    31 dic</string>
            <string>    14 gen</string>

    </row>
    <row>
        <string>Media Nord</string>
            <number>    101.60  </number>
            <number>    101.85  </number>
            <number>    101.84  </number>
            <number>    101.84  </number>
            <number>    280 </number>

    </row>
    <row>
        <string>Media Sud</string>
            <number>    101.24  </number>
            <number>    101.70  </number>
            <number>    101.88  </number>
            <number>    101.88  </number>
            <number>    280 </number>

    </row>
</chart_data>
```

After the second round of the PHP script:

```
<chart>
<axis_category color='ffffff' skip='0' size='12' alpha='80' />
<axis_value color='ffffff' skip='10' size='12' show_min='false' min="80" max="130"  />
<chart_border top_thickness='1' bottom_thickness='1' left_thickness='1' right_thickness='1' />              
<chart_data>
    <row>
        <null/>
            <string>    17 dic</string>
            <string>    24 dic</string>
            <string>    14 gen</string>
            <string>    14 gen</string>

    </row>
    <row>
        <string>Media Nord</string>
            <number>    101.60  </number>
            <number>    101.84  </number>
            <number>    280 </number>


            <number>    280 </number>

    <row>
        <string>Media Sud</string>
            <number>    101.24  </number>
            <number>    101.70  </number>
            <number>    280 </number>


    </row>
            <number>    280 </number>
```

I'd also be happy if I could have only one PHP file instead of 2, but I have no idea how to do that.

Is this the best way to modify this XML file, or is there another way?

Notice that the new line that will be written to HTML from a user.

I have this "start" script for deleting the content I want to delete.

What do you think of it?

```
<?php
$file = '/...../test.xml';


$fp = fopen(file,"w"); // open it for WRITING ("w")

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {

    //do actions here
    $xml = file_get_contents($file);
    $sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    echo '<pre>';

    // "delete the 1th string of row 1, etc."
    unset($sxe->chart_data->row[0]->string[0]);
    unset($sxe->chart_data->row[1]->number[0]);
    unset($sxe->chart_data->row[2]->number[0]);

    $sxe->chart_data->row[0]->addChild('string', 'test');
    $sxe->chart_data->row[1]->addChild('number', '999');
    $sxe->chart_data->row[2]->addChild('number', '9999');

    file_put_contents($file, $sxe->asXML());


    // unlock the file
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);

} else {

    // flock() returned false, no lock obtained
    print "Could not lock $file!\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Use PHP's XMLReader to parse XML. http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php

Comment: `$filePath = '/test.xml';` Is the file *really* in your server root?

Comment: Of course not... that was only as example for this question.
I'm not shure if it's worth to learn XMLReader to do such a little change on the file...

Comment: What's the problem you're having when you try to combine the two scripts? You just need to adjust the indexes when you do the replacements, because they need to refer to the line numbers in the original file, not the ones after the lines have been deleted.

Comment: Editing an XML file by line numbers... Have you tried an XML parser/writer?!

Comment: Another way to look at it is that this question isn't really about editing XML, it's about deleting and replacing lines in a text file. They happen to be XML in this case, but that seems to be incidental.

Comment: A minor point: `file_put_contents($filename, $array)` is exactly the same as `file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $array))`--the array will be imploded for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you `unset()` an array member you change the line numbers. This is easy to demonstrate:

```
$origfile = array(
    "line1\n",
    "line2\n",
    "line3\n",
);

unset($file[1]); // delete line 2

$round1file = implode('', $file); // "write the file"
```

The result is a *two-line* file, not a *three-line* file!

```
line1
line3
```

So when you read it in again, your array will look like this:

```
$round1file = array("line1\n","line3\n");
```

If you delete line 2 again, you will obviously be left with `array("line1\n")`

The immediate solution is to *replace* the line with a blank line rather than to *unset* the array member, i.e. `$fileArr[7] = "\n"` instead of `unset($fileArr[7])`.

**However, what you are doing is completely insane.** This is an XML file, so you need to parse and write it with an XML library or I guarantee you *you will end up with invalid XML* sooner or later! Also, **you cannot safely write over a file that multiple processes may be using**--you need to use some sort of file locking or a proper database.

For file locking, you can use a pair of functions like this:

```
function file_get_contents_locked($filename)
{
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'rb');
    if ($fp===FALSE) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not open file '{$filename}'");
    }
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_SH)) {
        $data = stream_get_contents($fp);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
        return $data;
    } else {
            fclose($fp);
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not acquire lock on file '{$filename}'");
    }
}


function file_put_contents_locked($filename, $data)
{
    return file_put_contents($filename, $data, LOCK_EX);
}
```

Or if you are on a *nix of some kind where renames are atomic, you can write to a temporary file and rename over the old file instead of using locking. (You don't need locking in this case because the file will never be half-read or half-written *as long as you write using this method*.)

```
function write_atomic($fullfilename, $data) {
    $tmpname = tempnam(dirname($fullfilename), 'write_atomic-');
    if (FALSE!==file_put_contents($tmpname, $data)) {
        rename($tmpname, $fillfilename);
    }
    unlink($tmpname);
}
```

For the XML manipulation, two easy options are [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) which is simpler but less powerful, and [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) which is more complex but more powerful. (You can also use XMLReader and XMLWriter, but these are much harder to use and much slower--they are only needed if you can't fit your entire XML file in memory at once.)

Here is an example to get you started. Look at the linked documentation for more details:

```
function delete_xml_stuff($filename)
{
    $xml = file_get_contents_locked($filename);
    $sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    // e.g., "delete the 2th string of row 1"
    unset($sxe->chart_data->row[0]->string[1]);
    file_put_contents_locked($filename, $sxe->asXML());

    // if you have more complex criteria, use DOMDocument:

    $d = new DOMDocument();
    $d->loadXML($xml);
    $xp = new DOMXPath($d);
    $results = $xp->query('//chart_data/row[2]/*[3]');
    if ($results->length) {
        $row2column3 = $results->item(0);
        $row2column3->parentNode->removeChild($row2column3);
    }
    file_put_contents_locked($d->saveXML());
}
```

Comment: Thank you, all XML files and php script you see here are under protection (apache .htaccess).
What you suggest as XML library, and where can I find a "real" guide how to use it? Thank you again!

Comment: `.htaccess` "protection" is irrelevant--what if two people (browsers) trigger a write to the file at the same time, or one browser reads while another browser is writing? Your file will get corrupted.

Comment: This file would will be readed by a swf file to generate a chart. So only one people can edit this file when logged on the site.
But as you said, this is not a good way to do this thing, so I would like to use an XML library

Comment: You can't *ever* have more than one swf file running at the same time?  That seems unlikely! I have extended my answer with an example.

Comment: I get a simple but functioning script (I posted it on the original question post, at the bottom)... what do you think about it? Will the file protection works? Now I only need to write the new data on it...

Comment: The file protection *will not* work because the `'w'` in your `fopen()` will truncate the file to zero bytes before you get a lock on it! Read [the documentation for the `'c'` mode of `fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for details. Also, you should communicate failures to the http client using a 5xx status code instead of a 200 code with an error message.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to use a xml library like DOMDocument/XPath or simplexml when working with xml. Regardless of fixing this bug or not you'll reach a point where XML handling the way you supposed will get very messy.

Have for example a look on [SimpleXML](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/simplexml.examples.php) and the examples on the page.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that editing through php was not the best way to do it... but learn how to use DOM (with SimpleXML I'm not able to delete a complete line if I understanded it right...) to do such a little modify... Maybe I'll theach to the users how to edit an XML and upload it to the website...